# Last row of datagrid appears unselectable

Tags: gwt, datagrid

Last row of datagrid appears unselectable if the cursor is slighly out of the bottom of the row. This can be reproduced in the [showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid).
For lines with small row height this can be a problem.
It has the effect that the row appears to be unselectable.
Has anyone noticed that? Is there a workaround?
Thanks

Comment: Looks related to this one: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7131

Comment: No it's not this one, the horizontal scrollbar is not involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue (unfortunately): https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7576

Answer (score 1):

I Have the same problem.
When clicked in the top, the selection appears normally, but below the cell's middle, the selection doesn't works.